# Inconsistent Classifier Updating in Weka [Scala]

Tags: scala, machine-learning, nlp, weka

I'm simultaneously updating two weka classifiers.

Here's how I'm updating the first classifier:

```
 List(X, Y, action).zipWithIndex.foreach{
   case (attrString:String, index)=> attrs.elementAt(index) match{
     case attr:Attribute => instance.setValue(attr,attrString)
   }         
 }
```

Here's how I'm updating the second classifier:

```
 List(X, name, Y).zipWithIndex.foreach{
   case (attrString:String, index) => tagattrs.elementAt(index) match{
     case attr:Attribute => {
       println("Setting taginstance's "+index+"th field to "+attrString)
       taginstance.setValue(attr, attrString)
     }
   }
 }
```

You'll notice the only difference(other than my debugging statement) is that /instance/ should have attributes /X, Y, action/, whereas /taginstance/ should have attributes /X, name, Y/

Then:
     println(instance)
     println(taginstance)

Unfortunately, this is what's output by these two functions:

```
Setting taginstance's 0th field to DT
Setting taginstance's 1th field to warm
Setting taginstance's 2th field to JJ
DT,JJ,SHIFT
DT,JJ,?
```

The first three lines indicate that it should be setting the correct values, but if this were the case, then the last line would read DT, warm, JJ.

What the heck!

Comment: Have you tried setValue(int,String) rather than setValue(Attribute,String)? If so, does the same behavior occur? [I don't actually know Scala, but it seems reasonably clear that it is the second you are currently doing.] [I added that disclaimer in case I'm wrong about what's going on. I blame my lack of Scala knowledge!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment by @Rehj led to me debugging the problem.
Unfortunately, I had the wrong set of attributes associated with the Instances.
Changing `attrs` to `tagattrs` in the following solved my problem. My bad!

```
 val tagdata = new Instances("Actions",tagattrs,10)
```